# Android. Repeating background only vertically

Tags: android

I've tries using `setTileModeXY(Shader.TileMode.REPEAT, Shader.TileMode.REPEAT)` for repeating a small image in the background. But i'd like to repeat it only vertically, not horizontally. What do i set the first or second parameter so it won't repeat? Can't figure it out, i'm sure it's something rudimentary.

Comment: Yeah, how the hell didn't i think of null !!! Please write your answer so I can accept it and be done with this post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried `null`? also consider that there are the single X and Y versions of the method.